# Chapter and verse numbers in memoir header

Tags: header-footer, numbering, memoir, verse

I was playing around with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244607/verse-numbers-in-memoir-header) and trying to extend the example with the following three features:

1. How do I rest the `num` for each `verse` environment (ending with the `\end{verse}`)?
2. The header should be `<current chapter number> : \firstmarks1 - \botmarks1` , e.g. `3:24-28` for Chapter 3, for respectively the 24th `\num` and 28th `\num` on the same page.
3. If the page ends with the same number for `\firstmarks1` and `\botmarks1` (i.e. on a tailing page or a very long verse), how can ensure it don't show up e.g. `3:29-29` but just `3:29` ?

**Update 1 (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,14pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\makepagestyle{myps}
\makeevenfoot{myps}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myps}{}{}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{myps}{}

\makeoddhead{myps}{\thepage}{\rightmark}{C: \firstmarks1{ }– \botmarks1}
\makeevenhead{myps}{C: \firstmarks1{ }– \botmarks1}{\rightmark}{\thepage}

\nouppercaseheads

\newcounter{verseno}
\newcommand{\num}{\refstepcounter{verseno}%
  \flagverse{\theverseno}\marks1{\theverseno}}
\setlength{\vleftskip}{\dimexpr\vleftmargin-.5em}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{myps}

\chapter{Flower}
\begin{verse}
\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{verse}

\chapter{Forest}
\begin{verse}
\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Desired header result (for the sample text) should look something like this:

Page 2:

```
1:4-5          Flower              2 
------------------------------------
```

Page 4:

```
2:4            Forest              4 
------------------------------------
```

Note 1: the sample currently shows `2:8` and not `2:4` on page 4, but the counter should restart for each use of `verse` environment.

Note 2: Even/odd pages work fine, they just switch the *page numbe* and *chapter:verse* numbers.

[@Peter Wilson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12082/peter-wilson)

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class (nor I think any other) saves the chapter title, so this is a small revision of your code to in the headers give chapter number and title in the center surrounded by the chapter number/verse numbers and page numbers.

```
% memverseprob.tex  SE 627870

\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,14pt,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\makepagestyle{myps}
\makeevenfoot{myps}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myps}{}{}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{myps}{}

%%%%%%%%%% change the headers/footers
%\makeoddhead{myps}{\thepage}{\rightmark}{C: \firstmarks1{ }– \botmarks1}
%\makeevenhead{myps}{C: \firstmarks1{ }– \botmarks1}{\rightmark}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{myps}{\thepage}{\leftmark}{\thechapter: \firstmarks1{ }– \botmarks1}
\makeevenhead{myps}{\thechapter: \firstmarks1{ }– \botmarks1}{\leftmark}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{myps}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{myps}{}{}{}


\nouppercaseheads

\newcounter{verseno}
\newcommand{\num}{\refstepcounter{verseno}%
  \flagverse{\theverseno}\marks1{\theverseno}}
\setlength{\vleftskip}{\dimexpr\vleftmargin-.5em}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{myps}

\chapter{Flower}
\begin{verse}
\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{verse}

\chapter{Forest}
\begin{verse}
\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}
\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}
\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\num Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

If you go with this then I suggest you remove the chapter number before the verse numbers in the `myps` pagestyle. Otherwise reconfigure the `\chapter` macro but you will have to find someone else to help you with that.

Comment: So this is an improvement but needs a bit before it's an answer. Firstly, if you e.g. delete the last to `\num Lorem ipsum` from your example, you still end up with the messy `2: 12-12` rather than `2:12` (i.e. when the page only have the range of 1 verse). Secondly, I agree the `\chapter` should not be redefined, that's somewhat of a hack, but rather a workaround with `\verse-section` or redefined/new command should be used to get the result of the center `1 Flower` and `2 Forest` in the header section.

Comment: @imdk4242 Good luck in your endeavours.